# Redirecting back to Angular app from external URL

Tags: angular, payment-gateway, angular-routing

I need to integrate payment gateway in an Angular app. The gateway is an external url provided by the bank. Once, the user clicks the payment button from the angular app, I was able to redirect to this external url. once the payment is successful, the external url will be redirected to an another external url. could you please provide me an solution on how to come back to the Angular from there

```
doPayment() {

    let params = {
        invoiceId: this.invoice.id,
        amount: this.invoice.amount
    }

    this.paymentService.payNow(params).subscribe((res:any) => {

        if(res.message){
            this._router.navigate(['/externalRedirect', { externalUrl: res.message.url }]);
        }

    })
}
```

In Routing

```
const externalUrlProvider = new InjectionToken('externalUrlRedirectResolver');

{
        path: 'externalRedirect',
        resolve: {
            url: 'externalUrlRedirectResolver'
        },
        data: {
            externalUrl: ''
        },
        component: someComponent
}
```

In Module

```
providers: [
  {
      provide: 'externalUrlRedirectResolver',
      useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
          const externalUrl = route.paramMap.get('externalUrl');
          window.open(externalUrl, '_self');
      },
}
```

Comment: does your payment gateway asked for a API url to call on success/fail ?

Comment: when the payment is successful, payment gateway will be re-directed to another external url, from there i need to get back to the Angular app

Comment: i have worked with two payment gateways. both had a option of setting up a API of my own which the payment gateway calls after on success or fail.

Comment: ok thanks. my scenario is different. i don't have a control over the external url